# Resources$NotFoundException with multi-module Compose tests

Tags: android, testing, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing

I have a multi-module Android project which includes a `core-ui` module with my Compose themes, reusable composables, and resources (fonts, drawables, etc). I have another module called `search` that includes the `core-ui` module as a dependency.

When I run my Compose tests in my `androidTest` folder, I get `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException` on several fonts. These fonts are located in `core-ui` and are used by `search`. When I run the actual app, however, the fonts are loaded without any issue.

How can I configure my `androidTest` tests to have access to these font resources from a different module?

Comment: I have a similar config and I actually have this error even in composable previews. Do you have the same? And did you find a solution?

Comment: No solution yet unfortunately... since it's not a blocking issue for me, I haven't had a chance to spend any time on it in a few weeks

Comment: yeah not blocking for me neither, but since previewable composables is one of the main benefits of Compose... :( In this case XML was better :S

Comment: I have this issue in a Compose preview with a AndroidView. The font is in the same module, but preview fails with this exception. For AndroidView logic I just now use isInEditMode and then do not load the font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran across this issue again and found the solution. Oddly enough the issue was caused from using the wrong resource in my `Font` definitions. I'm actually not sure why it worked when I was running the app rather than a UI test.

My tests were failing with this

```kotlin
val gotham = FontFamily(
    Font(R.font.gotham_300, Thin),
    ...
)
```

where `R.font.gotham_300` is a file `gotham_300.xml` that defines the font-family.

I changed it to point to `gotham_light.otf` instead, and it resolved the issue.

```kotlin
val gotham = FontFamily(
    Font(R.font.gotham_light, Thin),
    ...
)
```